Prove that $x^xy^y+x^yy^x \le 1$ if $x+y=1$ and $x,y$ are positive
Given $x+y=1$, $x>0$, $y>0$, prove that
$$x^xy^y+x^yy^x \le 1.$$
I first tried using lagrangian, $\mathcal{L}=f(x,y)-\lambda(g(x,y)-c)$ where $f(x,y)=x^xy^y+x^yy^x $ ,$g(x,y)=x+y$  and  $c=1$, but it turned out to be way too complex to solve.
Then I tried to get rid of $y$, resulting
$$1+\left(\frac{1-x}{x}\right)^{2x-1} \le\left(\frac{1-x}{x} \right)^{x}\frac{1}{1-x} $$ which I have absolute no idea how to go on.

Yes. Thanks @Gary
